# View Eclipse Run As configurations from filesystem

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm interested in viewing (not configuring/changing, just viewing) the Maven run configurations I've created created - and not from Eclipse's dialog/window but via finding them in the filesystem and viewing them in some ordinary text editor.

Can they be viewed this way? In which location are they stored?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You find the configuration files (XML) relative to your workspace in

```
.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches/*.launch
```

I found them using unix tools (In case the location has changed, e.g. new version of eclipse)

```
find . -exec  grep "UNIQUESTRING" {} \; -print
```

As UNIQUESTRING you could use some parameter entered in the dialog.

Comment: Thanks! this was definitely what I was searching for.

Answer (score 1):

You could save run/debug configuration as shared file. This option is on last tab of Run/Debug Configuration ("Common").

Comment: Nice to know for future use, but at this moment my Workspace doesn't launch, therefore I need to browse them from filesystem.